# Dell Inspiron custom buttons

Tags: 12.04, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 14R that out of the box came out with Ubuntu 11.1. Ass suggested here, I upgraded it to Ubuntu 12.04.

My laptop keyboard has three funny buttons in the upper-left corner. According to the manual, they are:

- Dell Instant Launch button
- Dell Audio With Preset Switch button
- Windows Mobility Center button

They do nothing when I press them, and by the name they seem Windows-oriented. I want to know if they have some utility in Ubuntu, and if they not if I can made them useful by some way (maybe launching some equivalent Ubuntu packages)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Mobility Center button actually generates `Meta + x` (or `Win + x` in windows terminology). You can set `Meta + x` as hotkeys to trigger an action, e.g. launch a program.

In KDE the settings are on `Custom Shortcuts`, `System Settings`.

Comment: Since your laptop is with Ubuntu pre-installed, I wonder if the other two special keys work out-of-the-box? I have a 15R SE with windows installed. I've been trying to make use of the other two keys on Linux.

Comment: would you be so kind as to post what you used to determine Meta+x was generated?  (I'd guess some command from a term/shell, but I have SO MUCH to learn about *nix.)

Comment: @PythonLarry I use `xev`. Just open a shell and start `xev`. A new window pops up. Ensure the window is the active one. You can press some letter keys and see the output. You can then press the special keys.

Comment: @majie I tried `xev` and nothing occurred (no events; in particular, no _KeyPress_ or _KeyRelease_ events), in opposition to actual `Meta + X` (which generated two _KeyPress_ and two _KeyRelease_ events)